# Enable Apache re-write engine in Ubuntu?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, mod-rewrite

How do I enable Apache re-write engine in Ubuntu hardy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `a2enmod rewrite` and put your rewrite rules into the Apache httpd configuration or your `.htaccsess` files.

Comment: Thanks.

It may be already be enabled, how do I confirm this?

Where would I find httpd config file in Ubuntu hardy?

Thanks.

Comment: See `/etc/apache2` and especially `/etc/apache2/mod-enabled`.